# ORA-12609: tns: receive timeout occurred- Error Occurs When Running Query to Create Tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, tablespace

Could any one help? I generate a script to create a tablespace from Oracle 12c (ASM), then run it into 19c (ASM as well). However, there is an error occurs ORA-12609: tns: receive timeout occurred.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE ARCH DATAFILE 
  '+DATA' SIZE 11400M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 100M MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
LOGGING
DEFAULT 
  NO INMEMORY
ONLINE
EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE
BLOCKSIZE 8K
SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO
FLASHBACK ON;
```

Please help. Thanks.

I try to set the parameters in sqlnet.ora as below:

```
SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3600
SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT=3600
SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT=3600
```

However, it does not work at all, the mentioned error keeps appearing after 20 secs.

Here is the alert logs.

```
2023-02-27T13:57:58.662314+07:00
ORA-1013 signalled during: CREATE TABLESPACE ARCH DATAFILE 
  '+DATA' SIZE 11400M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 100M MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
LOGGING
DEFAULT 
  NO INMEMORY
ONLINE
EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE
BLOCKSIZE 8K
SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO
FLASHBACK ON...
2023-02-27T13:59:01.455679+07:00
NOTE: Using default ASM root directory ASM
NOTE: Using default ASM root directory ASM
NOTE: Using default ASM root directory ASM
NOTE: Using default ASM root directory ASM
```

Comment: The ASM disk space is not full.

Comment: What does the alert log show?

Comment: Please edit that into the question as formatted/readable text, not as comments.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have edited the question, adding alert logs. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue. That error due to bad SQL format.

Thank you for your help!